# Modal dialog to show when link is clicked and button to point to window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have a "Delete Account" link. I want to show a dialog box confirmation when this link is clicked.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jPzj6/

The problem is that in this code, the confirmation "Are you sure you want to delete your account?" is already showing.

I also want to show the dialog box with the Delete button linking to:

```
window.location = bender.base_url + '?page=user&action=delete&id=' + bender.user.id  + '&secret=' + bender.user.secret;
```

and the Close button to simply close the dialog box.

I wanted to make it look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/vvjj8/

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just copy code from example. Your code has lack of buttons identifiers

```
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(true);
        },
            "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(false);
        }
    }
```

and for some reason, in your code `buttons` is array and in example it is object. Also, you have undefined value of `bender`, you should create object before fill it

```
var bender = {};
```